# oracle trigger pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, view, triggers, insert

I have a database user that contains four tables `department`, `employee`, `address` and `contact info`, then stored 5 Records in each table, and wrote the PL/SQL Statement for the following:

Stored a record into `employee`, `address` and `contact` using trigger.

the insert into view is not working ! it results in error ? can you guys help me with this ?
this is my code :

```
-- Create Tables :

CREATE TABLE address (
code int primary key,
city varchar2(30),
street varchar2(30)
);


create table Department (
DepId int primary key ,
Dep_Name varchar2(30) ,
Dep_adress varchar(30));


create table Employee (
Emp_Id int primary key ,
firstName varchar2(30),
lastName varchar2(30),
salary int,
Dep_Id int references Department (DepId),
Code int references address (code));


CREATE TABLE contact_info (
email varchar2(30) primary key ,
phone int ,
EmpId int references Employee (Emp_Id));

-- insert   :

insert into Department values (1,'IT','Amman');
insert into Department values (2,'CS','Jerash');
insert into Department values (3,'accounting','Amman');
insert into Department values (4,'managment','Amman');
insert into Department values (5,'employment','Amman');




insert into address values (50,'Amman','AAA');
insert into address values (60,'Amman','AAB');
insert into address values (70,'Amman','AAC');
insert into address values (80,'Jerash','AAD');
insert into address values (90,'Irbid','AAE');




insert into Employee (Emp_Id,firstName,lastName,salary,Dep_Id,Code) values (1,'john' , 'samo' , 1000 , (select DepId from Department where Dep_Name = 'IT'),(select code from address where street = 'AAA'));
insert into Employee (Emp_Id,firstName,lastName,salary,Dep_Id,Code) values (2,'mark' , 'wol' , 2000 , (select DepId from Department where Dep_Name = 'IT'),(select code from address where street = 'AAB'));
insert into Employee (Emp_Id,firstName,lastName,salary,Dep_Id,Code) values (3,'ahmad' , 'moh' , 1100 , (select DepId from Department where Dep_Name = 'IT'),(select code from address where street = 'AAC'));
insert into Employee (Emp_Id,firstName,lastName,salary,Dep_Id,Code) values (4,'maher' , 'imk' , 1700 , (select DepId from Department where Dep_Name = 'CS'),(select code from address where street = 'AAD'));
insert into Employee (Emp_Id,firstName,lastName,salary,Dep_Id,Code) values (5,'ali' , 'geh' , 1200 , (select DepId from Department where Dep_Name = 'CS'),(select code from address where street = 'AAE'));




insert into contact_info values ('john@gmail.com',0785602200, (select Emp_Id from Employee where salary = 1000));
insert into contact_info values ('mark@gmail.com',0785602201, (select Emp_Id from Employee where salary = 2000));
insert into contact_info values ('ahmad@gmail.com',0785602202, (select Emp_Id from Employee where salary = 1100));
insert into contact_info values ('maher@gmail.com',0785602203, (select Emp_Id from Employee where salary = 1700));
insert into contact_info values ('ali@gmail.com',0785602204, (select Emp_Id from Employee where salary = 1200));




-- trigger :



CREATE VIEW vw_address1 AS
    SELECT 
        code,
        city, 
        street
    FROM 
        address;
    

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_trg2
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON vw_address1
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    l_code NUMBER;
BEGIN
    -- insert a new address first
    INSERT INTO address(code,city, street)
    VALUES(:NEW.code,:NEW.city, :NEW.street)
    RETURNING code INTO l_code;
    
END;

insert into vw_address1(code,city,street) values (2,'Amman','AAB');
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include the full error you get in the question. What you've posted [seems to work OK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c357ee5e7fd014792e3d198c309b1cae). How did you run the code; if as a script, you're missing a `/` at the end of the trigger? (Why are you using a view and trigger - sounds like an exercise you've been given?)

Comment: You do not need `instead of` trigger to redirect insert into the original table. Use plain insert into view

Comment: A comment on your design.  You have a table ADDRESS.  Fine.  Then in your table DEPT, you have a column ADDRESS you have a column DEP_ADDRESS, and the data you are putting in it is the same as in the ADDRESS table.  Bad.  Instead, the DEP_ADDRESS column should be a FK  pointing back to the PK of the ADDRESS table.

Comment: A comment on coding style.  You should think through a rigorous naming standard.  It will pay off in the long run.  You 'clarify' some names with CamelCaseNames, and others with underscore_delimited_names.  Since oracle, by default, is case-INsensitive, it makes more sense to go with the underscore_delimited.  Forget your prior experience with mssql.  "When in Rome (oracle) ..."